# Display thumbnails using literal and bring large image on click event dynamically

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, thumbnails, literals

My website is based on  C#.net. I've a folder in which the user can place unknown number of images. Each image has a thumbnail version and large size.

For example, if image name is "car.jpg", the thumbnail image will be thcar.jpg" (i.e., just append "th" before image name).

**In my pageload event, I want to display all these thumbnail images using asp:literal. When the user clicks a thumbnail image, I want to display the larger size of that image in a asp:image above thumbnails.**

Can anyone help me with this? Code in jquery or javascript will be more useful, whereas I am happy with C# code also....
Thanks in advance,

Edit: My web page should look like

```
 ____________________
|                    |
|  Larger image      |
|                    |
|____________________|
```

Thumbnail images,

```
 _   _   _   _
|_| |_| |_| |_|
```

Whenever a thumbnail is clicked, the larger version of thumbnail image should be displayed....

Comment: It irritates me a lot to  witness people writing relatively long questions without any line breaks.

Comment: @Joonas: Really sorry for the inconvenience caused. I will correct myself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made a basic example too:

http://jsbin.com/utijid/1

its source is here:

http://jsbin.com/utijid/1/edit

Comment: Seems kind of wasteful/timeconsuming to put all of the big images there in the html and just hide them. What if you'd have 300 images...? That would mean lots of _unnecessary_ copy/pasting.

Comment: @Joonas if there is a lot of images than one preview is enough and its src attribute must be changed. But if there is not too much image than this is better, because the image will shown immediately after clicking on thumb.

Comment: If I wanted to show images instantaneously on click, I wouldn't do it this way cause it's just so much manual labor. You could of course do about the same thing by preloading the big images in a more automatic way with jquery, but it is still quite a lot of work, I would just go with a loading image that is shown before the image is loaded. Easiest way to add loading image would be to just put a background image into the parent container of the big images. Background image that would be a centered loading image .gif. Maybe I'm just lazy, but as they say: "Time is monkey"